# Why does this for-loop paralellization doesn't work in Python?

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, tqdm

I need to navigate across 10,000 folders, collect some data from each folder, add it to 3 containers (c18, c17, c16, 3 initially empty lists each of which will be populated with 10,000 numbers) and it would take forever without parallellization.

My aim is to iterate through all folders with a for-loop (for i in range(10000)) and append 3 values extracted from each folder to c18, c17, c16 respectively, at each iteration of the for-loop.
I also want to display a progress bar - to know roughly how long would it take.

I have never parallelized a loop before or included a progress bar. I have tried to use SO. After reading some answers, I got to the point at which I wrote:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
pool.imap(funct, tqdm.tqdm(range(len(a0s))) # or pool.map(funct, tqdm.tqdm(range(len(a0s))))
```

`len(a0s)` yields 10,000.

The function `funct` is `def funct(i):` and does what I wrote above: for a given folder defined using the for-loop variable `i` (current iteration number), it does the job of extracting 3 values and appending them to c18, c17, c16.

I am calling `pool.imap(funct, tqdm.tqdm(range(len(a0s)))` inside a `main()` function and at the end of the .py script I wrote :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am importing:

```
import processing
import tqdm
```

However, all the above doesn't work.
How shall I proceed? Any help is welcomed.
Thanks!

```
a0s = np.loadtxt("Intensity_Wcm2_versus_a0_10_21_10_23_range.txt", usecols=(1,)) # has 10,000 entries
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)

top_folder_path = os.getcwd()
base_path = top_folder_path + "/a0_"

for i in range(len(a0s)):
    results_folder = base_path + "{:.4f}".format(a0s[i])
    if os.path.isdir(results_folder):
        os.chdir(results_folder)
        S = happi.Open(".")
        pbb = S.ParticleBinning(0).get() # charge states diagnostic
        c18.append(pbb['data'][-1][-1]) # first -1 is for last timestep recorded by diagnostic, second -1 is for last charge state (bare ions, Ar18+)
        c17.append(pbb['data'][-1][-2])
        c16.append(pbb['data'][-1][-2])
        print("###########################################################]#########")
        print("We have done the folder number: " + str(i) + " out of: " + str(len(a0s)))
        os.chdir(top_folder_path)

    else:
        continue
 
 def funct(i):
    results_folder = base_path + "{:.4f}".format(a0s[i])
    if os.path.isdir(results_folder):
        os.chdir(results_folder)
        S = happi.Open(".")
        pbb = S.ParticleBinning(0).get() # charge states diagnosti
        c18_val = pbb['data'][-1][-1]
        c17_val = pbb['data'][-1][-2]
        c16_val = pbb['data'][-1][-3]
        c18.append(c18_val)
        c17.append(c17_val)
        c16.append(c16_val)
    else:
        return

def main():
    pool.imap(funct, tqdm(range(len(a0s))))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Don't describe the code. Show the actual code as a [mcve].

Comment: Understand, trying to do it now.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, does it look better now? Thanks

Comment: It's not a [mcve], but it's better.  I'll write you a generic example of using tqdm with multiprocessing since the code isn't runnable for me as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a template for multiple progress bars and multiprocessing.  Hope it helps.  I set it up to expect to be updated 10 times in each process and added a sleep to be the parallelized "work".

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import tqdm
import time
from itertools import repeat

def funct(lock,i):
    with lock:
        bar = tqdm.tqdm(position=i,total=10,leave=False,ncols=100)
    bar.set_lock(lock)
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(.2)
        bar.update(1)
    bar.close()
    return i*2

def main():
    lock = mp.Manager().Lock()
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(funct, zip(repeat(lock),range(8)))
    print()
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I have almost understood it all. However, I cannot get the result in there. The program simply enters an infinite loop (or similar) after finishing loading the first progress bar. It doesn't print the result. I suspect result shall be a number, because funct returns i*2 always. Actually, it doesn't print anything I tell it to print after the with mp.Pool() as pool: block of instructions. I need to quit python using Ctrl+Z (keyboard interrupt)